# Using Poincaré-Bendixson to prove that there is a periodic solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I want to use the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem to show that there exists a nontrivial (and periodic) solution to $$z'' + [\log (z^2 +4(z')^2)]z' + z = 0.$$

Therefore I substituted $u = z'$ to get $$u' = - \log(z^2 + 4u^2) u - z, \quad z' = u.$$

We haven't covered the theorem in our classes yet, so I just try to follow the page 10 from [these dynamical systems notes](http://w3.ele.tue.nl/fileadmin/ele/MBS/CS/Files/Courses/Dynamical_Systems/dynsh8.pdf). I think that we can differentiate $f$ on every open set disjoint with $(0,0)$, but what would the $\mathcal S$ be here? How to proceed?

Here is the plot of dynamical system mentioned above and a sample trajectory starting from $(-5,5)$.

[image]

Comment: The simplest idea works: try the energy $H(z,u)=z^2+u^2$ and an annulus $r^2<H(z,u)<R^2$ for some suitable $(r,R)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Did's hint is correct. Here is a complete answer:
 Consider a Lyapunov function of the form
$$V(u,z)=u^2+z^2.$$
We have 
$$
V'(u,z)=2(uu'+zz')=-2u^2\log(z^2+4u^2),\\
$$
where the derivative is taken respect to $t$.
Now consider the annulus $A$ defined by:
$$\frac{1}{4}\leq u^2+z^2\leq1.$$
First, there is no stationary point in $A$ since the only stationary point of the system is $(0,0)$. Second, we verify that $A$ is indeed a trapping region so that we can apply Poincaré-Bendixson theorem:

$$u^2+z^2\leq\frac{1}{4}\implies\log(z^2+4u^2)\leq0\implies V'(u,z)\geq0,$$
$$u^2+z^2\geq1 \implies\log(z^2+4u^2)\geq0\implies  V'(u,z)\leq0.$$
This implies that the flows are going outward on $u^2+z^2=\frac14$ the inner boundary of $A$ and going inward on $u^2+z^2=1$ the outer boundary of $A$. Thus, every semi-orbit that starts within $A$ remains in $A$ forever. Thus, $A$ is indeed a trapping region.
Now Poincaré-Bendixson theorem implies that there exists a periodic orbit within $A$.

Comment: I have never heard about Lapunov functions, energies and flows, but I think that I understand the solution. Could you please advise me a book, where these notions are explained or tell me how did you learn about them?

Comment: Basically, Lyapunov function is the same in nature as energy function here, see Wiki [Lyapunov function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function). You might want to check Carmen Chicone's book: *Ordinary Differential Equations with Applications* for more detailed introduction on these concepts:)