# Existence of a periodic solution - Poincaré-Bendixson theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to show that the following equation has a nontrivial periodic solution $$x'' + [\ln (2x^2 +(x')^2)]x' + x = 0.$$

I substituted $ y = x $, $ z = x'$ to get $$z' = - \ln(2y^2 + z^2) z - y, \quad y' = z.$$

Using polar coordinate, we obtain $$ yy'+zz'=rr'. $$

Thus, $$ rr' = yz- \ln(2y^2 + z^2)z^2-yz = - \ln(2y^2 + z^2)z^2. $$ Now consider the region $A$ defined by:
$$\frac{1}{2}\leq 2y^2+z^2\leq2.$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\leq 2y^2+z^2\leq\ 1\implies\ln(2y^2+z^2)\leq0\implies r'\geq0,$$
$$1\leq 2y^2+z^2\leq 2 \implies\ln(2y^2+z^2)\geq0\implies  r'\leq0.$$ Also, since the region $A$ doesn't contain any critical point(which is $(0,0)$) of this system, we can use the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem to conclude that there exists a periodic solution.

> **My question is as follows :
>    According to my textbook (Elementary differential equations and Boundary value problems by Boyce, Di Prima), we should show that there is a solution of this system that stays in $A$ for all  $t\geq{t_0}$ for some ${t_0}$ to use the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem . How can we assure this? I think we can infer this from the information about r', but I'm a bit unclear**.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1282271/). $1/2 \leq 2 y^2 + z^2 \leq 2$ is not a trapping region because the trajectory can still cross the outer ellipse in the outward direction even though $r$ decreases.